# How to pass a global object around React Native components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, es6-class, es6-modules

I am trying to set up a messaging module in my React Native app, which should get information from a service and render it in different components in different ways. Kind of like the inbox messages here: you receive a message, and in the header component you see the inbox with a red dot and the number of new messages. If you click it, you go to another component that renders the messages fully.

Now, I created two components to render the inbox in those two different ways. But when I try link them to the class that handles the notifications, I get errors inside the components classes saying that the object is undefined.

I have something like this:

**Class that stores new messages**

```
class Notifications {
    constructor() {
        this.notifications = [];
    }

    receiveNotification(notif) {
        this.notifications.push(notif);
    }
}

let notifications = new Notifications();

export { notifications };
```

**Class that handles new messages from service**

```
import framework from 'framework'; // this is the framework I use to communicate with the service
import Notifications from './Notifications.js';

export class PushNotificator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    framework.requestPermissions()
    .then(() => console.log('granted'))
    .catch(() => console.log('notification permission rejected'));


    framework.getToken().then(token => {
      console.log("TOKEN (getToken)", token);
      this.setState({token: token});
    });

    this.notificationListener = framework.on(frameworkEvent.Notification, notif => {
      console.log("Notification", notif);
      this.showLocalNotification(notif);
    })
  }

  showLocalNotification(notif) {
    Notifications.notifications.push(notif); // this fails because Notifications is undefined
    framework.presentLocalNotification({
      title: notif.title,
      body: notif.body,
      priority: "high",
      click_action: notif.click_action,
      show_in_foreground: true,
      local: true
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.notificationListener.remove();
  }


  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Relevant part of the header inbox component**

```
import Notifications from './Notifications.js' //assume the paths are correct 
import {PushNotificator} from './PushNotificator.js'

export class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            notifications: Notifications.notifications.find(notif => notif.seen).length
        };

        this.closeActivityIndicator = () => setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
        }, 2000);
    }

...
render() {
    <PushNotificator />
    ...
}
```

As soon as the constructor is called, the program fails because Notifications is undefined. But why is it undefined? Can I not use it this way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options,  I see, how to fix your issue:

**1.** You have already instantiated your `Notifications`, so it is possible to export that instance by default without additional wrapping:

```
export default notifications;
```

and then just:

```
import notifications from './Notifications.js';
// ...
notifications.push(notif);
```

**2.** If you don't want to use the `default`, you may continue exporting your instance via

```
export { notifications };
```

and in that case you need to import it properly:

```
import { notifications } from './Notifications.js';
// ...
notifications.push(notif);
```

But in both cases you are working with instatiated `notifications` object, not with `Notifications` class.

Comment: That did it. Thank you.